# SQL - INSERT INTO from 2 tables into third?

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables - producers, products, offers. The first contains ProducerID and ProducerName, the second contains ProductID and ProductName, and the third has ProducerID and ProductID. I want the user to input ProducerName and ProductName and SQL to SELECT the ProducerID and ProductID from the other two tables and INSERT INTO the third junction table. How should my SQL statement look like to do that?

Should it be something like this:

```
sql = `INSERT INTO offers (ProducerID, ProductID) SELECT ProducerID FROM producers WHERE ProducerName="${ProducerName}", SELECT ProductID from products WHERE ProductName="${ProductName}"`
```

or should I be using a AND statement instead of a coma between the two SELECT statements? Or should my approach be totally different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming only 1 record will be returned for ProducerID and ProductID:

```
INSERT INTO offers (ProducerID, ProductID) VALUES (
(SELECT TOP 1 ProducerID FROM producers WHERE ProducerName="${ProducerName}"), 
(SELECT TOP 1 ProductID from products WHERE ProductName="${ProductName}")
)
```

Also be sure to properly parameterize the ProducerName and ProductName since it is coming from user input to prevent SQL Injection.

Comment: Didn't know such syntax would work though. Great to know!

Comment: I wasn't 100% sure either! I had to try it in SSMS before posting.

Comment: Yep, all product and producer names and ids are unique, so only one record will be returned. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Anytime! Good luck on your project.

Answer (score 1):

You can insert only from a single select, so:

```
INSERT INTO offers(ProducerID, ProductID)
SELECT ProducerID, ProductID
FROM producers, products
WHERE ProducerID = "${ProducerName}" AND ProductID = "${ProductName}"
```